# Sort graph bar by target variables, followed by sort variables

Tags: stata

I make a lot of graphs comparing two groups (e.g., male/female) across a number of variables. The standard -graph bar- output groups all bars for men together, and all bars for women together. I am hoping to find a simple way to make bar graphs that group bars first by the target variable (i.e. the variables being graphed), and then by the -over- variable, such as gender.

I have a method for doing this, but it is quite cumbersome.  See illustration below.

```
*Set seed + obs
clear
set seed 442
set obs 100

*Generate two outcomes
gen x1 = uniform()
gen x2 = uniform()

*Generate crossing variable
gen gender = 0 in 1/50
replace gender = 1 in 51/100
label define gender_lab 0 "Male" 1 "Female"
label values gender gender_lab

*Extract means by gender
gen b_male = .
gen b_female = .
sum x1 if gender == 0 
replace b_male = r(mean) in 1
sum x1 if gender == 1
replace b_female = r(mean) in 1
sum x2 if gender == 0
replace b_male = r(mean) in 2
sum x2 if gender == 1
replace b_female = r(mean) in 2

*Establish order of graph
gen index_male = _n*3 in 1/2
gen index_female = (_n*3) + 1 in 1/2


*This is what -graph bar- produces naturally
graph bar x1 x2, over(gender)

*This is closer to what I want
twoway bar b_male index_male || bar b_female index_female, xlabel(3.5 "x1" 6.5 "x2", notick labgap(4)) xmlabel(3 "Male" 4 "Female" 6 "Male" 7 "Female") legend(off)
```

Is there a simple way to use `graph bar` but still establish the sort order I want?  I produce dozens of these graphs per day sometimes, so I want to avoid unnecessary steps as much as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a model question: thank you very much!

I'll first copy your code, with some small simplifications which may be of interest any way.

```
*Set seed + obs
clear
set seed 442
set obs 100

*Generate two outcomes
gen x1 = runiform()
gen x2 = runiform()

*Generate crossing variable
gen gender = _n > 50 
label define gender_lab 0 "Male" 1 "Female"
label values gender gender_lab

*Extract means by gender
sum x1 if gender == 0 
gen b_male = r(mean) in 1
sum x1 if gender == 1
gen b_female = r(mean) in 1
sum x2 if gender == 0
replace b_male = r(mean) in 2
sum x2 if gender == 1
replace b_female = r(mean) in 2

*Establish order of graph
gen index_male = _n*3 in 1/2
gen index_female = (_n*3) + 1 in 1/2

*This is what -graph bar- produces naturally
graph bar x1 x2, over(gender) name(G1) 

*This is closer to what I want
twoway bar b_male index_male || bar b_female index_female, ///
xlabel(3.5 "x1" 6.5 "x2", notick labgap(4))                ///
xmlabel(3 "Male" 4 "Female" 6 "Male" 7 "Female") legend(off) name(G2)
```

The good news is that there is a one-line solution once you have installed `statplot` by Eric A. Booth and myself from SSC. (The email address for Eric is the help file is no longer current.)

```
ssc inst statplot 
statplot x1 x2, over(gender)
statplot x1 x2, over(gender) recast(bar)
statplot x1 x2, over(gender) recast(bar) asyvars yla(, ang(h)) ///
bar(2, bcolor(orange*0.8)) bar(1, bcolor(blue*0.8))
```

Here is the last graph to show what is done.

`statplot` defaults to means, what is what you show, so you don't have to calculate means. Other statistics are available.

[image]

Comment: I had heard of -statplot- once, but forgot about it. I'm glad to be reminded of it and with a perfect illustration fixing my problem.  Thanks!

Comment: I too forget about it sometimes, and I am its second author.